# How to analyze a pattern of discrete events belonging to a 24 hour and ~90 minute cycle?

Tags: discrete-signals, real-time

I'm a sleep researcher and since last december I've been collecting data on mydreaming and awakening in the middle of the night.

Dreaming occurs within a well-known 80-120 minute "cycles", with about 5-6 cycles within a typical night. Each cycle is defined by 4 stages, from light sleep to deep sleep to dreaming. I'm lucky enough that most of the time I wake up after or close to the dreaming sleep stage.

The start of the sleep cycles depends on the choice of bedtime, which in turn is governed by a larger, ~24.5 hour circadian rhythm, which is entrained by the light/dark cycle. 
The circadian rhythm is exhibited by all cells within a body as well as major organ systems.

**What I'm trying to do is better understand the circadian rhythm by analyzing discrete awakening events that I experience over night.** On the attached screenshots;
Each row represents one day of data. The events are plotted in real time.

Each discrete awakening from a  dream is marked in **green**

Each non-dream awakening is marked in **red**

Each lucid - conscious dream is marked in **cyan**.

Each morning "get out of bed" time is marked in **Orange**

The onset of the first sleep cycle is marked in **black**.

Each row has 2 rulers:

The **purple ruler**'s ticks are 90 minutes apart - the approximate sleep cycle length

The **cyan ruler** represents real time starting with 0 midnight, going to noon.

Together, the markers form vertical patterns, with dream awakenings happening at approximately the same times on subsequent days, with the pattern sloping one way or the other.

**How can I analyze hundreds of discrete data points like that to see if they do form some kind of a waveform that persists from day to day?**

I would be grateful for the keywords related to the transforms or algorithms that can help make more sense of such data, as well as any engineering articles dealing with a similar problem, or any other input.

Thank you!

[Full 90 day sleep history](http://luciddreamingapp.com/my-90-day-sleep-history/)

[image: Sleep Data 1]

[image: Sleep Data 2]

Comment: You could look at the peaks of the autocorrelation but you need a time series. You will not get anywhere with just these pictures.

Comment: Yeah, your first step is to figure out how to export this data into a usable format.

Comment: I have data in excel with the times of each event. Thanks for the autocorrelation suggestion!